# Secure Elasticsearch installation retrospectively

Tags: security, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch installation (V7.3.2). Is it possible to secure this retrospectively? [This link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-passwords.html) states that a password can only be set "during the initial configuration of the Elasticsearch". Basically, I require consumers of the restful API to provide a password (?) going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elastic [bootstrap password](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/built-in-users.html#bootstrap-elastic-passwords) is used to [init](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/setup-passwords.html) the [internal/reserved users](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/built-in-users.html) used by the components or features of the elastic stack (kibana, logstash, beats, monitoring, ...).

If you want to secure the API, you need to create [users/roles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/authorization.html) for your scenario on top.

**Please use [TLS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/encrypting-communications.html) in your cluster when handling with passwords and don't expose the cluster directly for security reasons.**

Here are all informations regarding a secure cluster including some tutorials: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/secure-cluster.html

EDIT: Added links as requested. Feel free to raise a new question here at SO if you're facing serious problems!

Comment: Thanks. Could you please refer me to the relevant doc (V7.3.2)? Thanks.

Comment: Please find the requested links above in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a [complete guide to install and secure ElasticSearch](https://botond-kopacz-84714.medium.com/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-installation-ecf44d06e7fe).

Basically the [bootstrap password](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/built-in-users.html#bootstrap-elastic-passwords) is used initially to setup the built-in ElasticSearch users (like "elastic", "kibana"). Once this is done, you won't be able access ElasticSearch anonymously but only with one of the built in users, e.g. "elastic".

Then you can use "elastic" user to [create additional users](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-put-user.html) (with their own password) and roles (e.g. to asses specific indexes only in read-only mode).

As @ibexit wrote it's highly recommended to secure your cluster and don't expose it directly (use a proxy server, secured with SSL).